Java Swing: Correct Rendering of Game Elements Across Different Screen Resolutions?
I'm developing a game using Java Swing and encountering issues with rendering game elements correctly across different screen resolutions.
In my GameFrame class, which sets up the game window, there's a nested class called GameCanvas. GameCanvas extends JComponent and handles rendering using the paintComponent method. Within GameCanvas, I call the draw method of a GameLogic object to render game objects onto the screen.
However, when running the game on systems with different screen resolutions (I use a Mac, and my partner uses Linux), the rendering of game elements, particularly the platforms, appears misplaced. For instance, while the bounding box (and its detected collision) is correct, the coordinates of the drawn rectangle are all weird.
In my program specifically, despite a box being said to be drawn at x = 300 in a window frame with dimensions (800, 600), the top-left corner of the drawn rectangle would instead be placed at x = 150. However, the bounding box and it's detected intersection is still at the right space. Why is that the case?
I've considered implementing resolution independence and scaling logic, but I'm not sure how to approach it effectively.
Could someone provide guidance on ensuring the correct rendering of game elements across different screen resolutions in a Java Swing application? Additionally, any best practices or examples would be greatly appreciated. I have also had this issue with previous projects as well. Thank you!

The issue has been resolved—it was simply a matter of resolution error in Java Swing. For anyone facing a similar issue in the future (with Java Canvas and Frame) ensure that the resolutions match each other. The discrepancy arises due to resolution settings, though the exact details are unclear.
If you are working on a Windows computer, adjust the settings as follows: Right-click on the desktop screen, navigate to Display Settings, and then adjust the Display Resolution to match.

Please consider posting an answer rather than answering your question in a comment.

I don't think that solution is of particular use, you can't tell people to "modify their screen resolution" to suit your needs.  If that's really the problem, I might consider making use of the full screen exclusive API, which would allow you to take control of the screen resolution yourself.  I think a better solution would revolve around having the GameCanvas pass it's current size to the drawing workflows an allow it to adapt.  You could even consider a "scaling" workflow where by you take the current size of the component and scale your rendering appropriately - just as a few ideas

To clarify my issue: what would happen on one device would not translate well to another. My computer ran at a display resolution of 1920 x 1080, while my partner's device ran at 1366 x 768. Even if the ContentPane had a setPreferredSize(600, 800), I encountered issues specifically with resolution. For instance, I could have a rectangle's top left corner drawn at coordinates (0, 600) and still appear, but not appear on my friend's screen. This issue was resolved by checking my screen resolution. There are, of course, better solutions out there. But that is what fixed my problem :)

If GameCanvas extended JPanel instead of JComponent, the second thing you do, right after the super.paintComponent call, is get the actual width and height of the drawing JPanel.  The methods are getWidth and getHeight.  You can test your drawing code by maximizing and restoring your JFrame.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Performing Custom Painting section.
